# Why does PHP's json_decode return a string when it should return an array?

Tags: php, json

I'm a bit confused as to why I'm not getting an array in my variable after I use json_decode().  I am using cURL to send some post data.  Here is what the post data looks like for cURL

```
upload, post_data: Array
(
    [local_file_path] => C:\videos\421F7D21-C659-43E1-9851-2397A4EEFB11.mp4
    [botr_video] => "{\"path\":\"\\\/v1\\\/videos\\\/upload\",\"query\":{\"token\":\"b34f75e5c2c4a23db9850b147f0440fc536bcc7a21847e29\",\"key\":\"hKwNuueB\"},\"protocol\":\"http\",\"address\":\"upload.bitsontherun.com\"}"
)
```

So I call cURL, and on the receiving side of the cURL call I have the following

```
$upload_link=json_decode($_POST['botr_video'], true); 
$file_path=$_POST['local_file_path']; 
$api_format="php"; 

error_log('upload link data is of type: '. gettype($upload_link));
```

When I go check my error log, it writes this:

```
upload link data is of type: string
```

Shouldn't that be an array?  The rest of the code in the receiving url depends on the json_decode to work.  Am I missing something?

Also, I logged the `$upload_link` variable after applying the json_decode function on the `$_POST['botr_video']` variable like this:

```
error_log('received upload link data: ' . print_r($upload_link, true));
```

Here is what I get in the log:

```
received upload link data: {"path":"\\/v1\\/videos\\/upload","query":{"token":"0835b9c46c0619cec9633a22bc9616a693696e4ea39a827c","key":"kRhvNuIF"},"protocol":"http","address":"upload.bitsontherun.com"}
```

Why doesn't json_decode take the post data and form an array?  It seems like it's leaving it as a string.

Comment: It seems your data is json-encoded _twice_. You should probably also post the code used to perform the POST request, as the problem is likely there.

Comment: In the event of a failure to decode, `json_last_error()` can be used to determine the exact nature of the error. But yes, we really need your source code :-)

Comment: if json_decode isn't returning an array something must be wrong with the input :/

Comment: @lanzz you were right, it was being encoded twice.

Comment: @linas Do you have to be so rude?

Comment: @lanzz's comment is the right answer. Solved for me. Thanks! :)